# How can I append text to label with button using swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to append text to label's text.
Example: 
Current label is a and when I pressed the button there should be 2 a characters

Comment: myLabel.stringValue = myLabel.stringValue + "a". you might want look up some sample apps and walk through to see how basic things are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a target to your button. Example:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And add your button pressed handler:

```
@objc
func buttonPressed() {
    guard let text = label.text else { return }
    label.text = text + "a"
}
```